# What database to use for CRM web app?

Tags: crm, postgresql, mongodb

I want to develop Java based CRM starting from scratch. I have noticed many notable open source CRM use Postgres. I need to choose between MongoDb and Postgres. I prefer MongoDb because there will be many changes in the database structure during development.

Is there any particular reason why majority of well known  open source CRM use Postgres?

Comment: I'm not sure if you gave sufficient criteria to allow for good matching recommendations: currently I only see "for CRM" (which would match almost any DB) and "many database structure changes during development" (which again sounds not that unusual). Are there any other criteria that need to be met? Think of specific features, targeted OS, licensing fees etc.

Comment: Relational databases like Postgres and the so-called “NoSQL” databases (document-oriented, or key-value-oriented) like Mongo serve very different purposes. Like comparing sports-cars to semi-trucks, not really comparable. And this is much too broad a Question for this Stack Exchange site.